# Add to Home Screen mini-info bar not showing on some devices

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am trying to implement my first PWA service worker and I have referred only google documentation. For now my manifest.json is complete and the service worker is a simple code as below.

```
// sw.js
var CACHE_NAME = "MyFirstPWA";
var filesToCache = [
   // some css and js files to cache
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    e.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);;
    }).then(function (e) {
       return self.skipWaiting();
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(function (cacheNames) {
        return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function (cacheName) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
        }));
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }));
});

// Manifest.json
{
  "name": "MyFirstPWA",
  "short_name": "MyFirstPWA",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=pwa&utm_medium=pwa",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#0054a6",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "scope": "/",
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

The working status of google's mini-info bar feature as below.

[image: Person vs Device working of mini-info bar]

I want to know if I am missing something or have implemented wrongly?
Please suggest.

Comment: Is this the first time your testers have visited your site? If not, you need to show them how to uninstall previous installs AND totally clear their browsers.

Comment: For desktop chrome, most people do not know the app is here. Make sure they right click and delete to see the install prompt again. chrome://apps/

Comment: For Mobile, make sure they look through their apps for your icon and UNINSTALL and then clear their browser cache. Settings > Privacy > Clear browsing Data > ADVANCED > All Time > Clear Data

Comment: @Mathias, For all the testers, this is still the first time as they have not yet installed the app either on desktop or on mobile, so the status posted by me is banner or mini-info bar showing status and not installing status

Comment: They may have tried twice and not realized that they dismissed? If you are sure then you need to see how current is their browser version. Clearing out everything almost always resolved issues for me.

Comment: Also, for the desktop version there is no mini-info bar. You list above says YES for two people?

Comment: @Mathias, I was there while they were testing and even after 2 mins or so, the mini-info bar did not show. Also, they are on the updated version. While checking we started by clearing all the browsing data of chrome browser

Comment: @Mathias, by desktop I mean the add to home screen link in chrome developer tools. So a "Yes" here mean that the link was working fine and a "No" means that the link is not working

Comment: Currently, the mini-info bar will show within the first few seconds, or not at all. Here is more info on what is showing with Chrome 68 and later: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Comment: Under which tab in the Dev tools do you see A2HS link? I didn't realise one was there.

Comment: Within Chrome Dev Tools, Application >> Manifest, you will get a Add to home screen option

Comment: @Mathias, check out the air horner chrome dev tools on desktop for add to home screen  on https://imgur.com/s9l1f2O

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that link was there. It looks like they have disabled it in the current version of chrome if the developer added (.preventDefault()) - there is an error in the console. This could be why it does not work for you. It does not work for me.

Comment: @Mathias, there is no error in either Yes or No case for me. Also, I have not implemented any .preventDefault() in my code